# Is the superclass a template for each subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the superclass `test` and two subclasses `test1` and `test2`.  I thought that if `test1` changes a field in `test`, that change would be seen by `test2` as well.  What I mean is

```
  test1 n = new test1();
  n.setX(5);
  test2 a = new test2();

  System.out.println(a.getX());
```

It returns 0 but I thought that since the field `x` was set to 5 it would show 5 when called.

Can you please clarify this confusion?

Comment: Is the field static?

Comment: Your classes should start with a capital letter. (see also: camel case)

Comment: You can't "change a field in a class" (unless it's static), you can only change a field in an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` and `a` are two **different instances**. Unless `X` is a `static` field, setting it from one instance should not affect the other instance, regardless of the fact that they are two different subclasses of the same super class.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how inheritance and instantiation works.

- Subtypes inherit the behaviour of the supertype.
- They do not inherit the state of any instances of all subtypes of a supertype.

This is no different to the fact that this prints 1

```
test1 n1 = new test1();
test1 n2 = new test1();
n1.setX(1);
n2.setX(2);
System.out.println(n1.getX()); // prints 1
```

The different *instances* have their own *state* even though they have the same behaviour. This is no different for subtypes of a supertype. All instances have their own *state* once they are created.

Of course, static fields (class variables) are always shared across all subtypes. So a change to that super's static field in one subtype will be seen in the other.

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub1 sub1 = new Sub1();
        Sub2 sub2 = new Sub2();
        sub1.setX(2);
        System.out.println(sub2.getX()); // prints 2
    }
}
class Super{
    private static int X;
    public int getX() { return X; }
    public void setX(int x) { X = x; }
}
class Sub1 extends Super {}
class Sub2 extends Super {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `setX` doesn't modify a static variable consider the following:

```
test n = new test1();
test a = new test2();
```

`n` and `a` are separate instances of `test` and therefore all of their modifications of any attributes of the superclass are only made to their own instances.  Attributes of a superclass are not shared by any instance of the subclass (unless they are static).

```
test n = new test1();
test a = n;
```

Notice the absence of the `new` qualifier in `a`'s declaration.  Now `a` and `n` share the same instance, so any modification made by `a` affects `n` and vice-versa.